# Why is my Linq statement being executed twice?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, mvc-mini-profiler

I am working on an internal message system. I have the mvc mini profiler hooked up, and it is showing me some statements are executed twice, and I can't figure out why,

My controller is as simple as you can get:

```
var db = MessagingDataContext.Get();
return db.Posts.OrderByDescending(p => p.DatePosted).Skip(pagenumber * pagesize).Take(pagesize);
```

and my view is just as simple (my _Layout page has the rest of the markup):

```
@foreach (var post in Model)
{
    <div class="post">
        <p>
            @Html.ActionLink(post.Title, "View", "Posts", new { postid = post.Id})  by @post.User.Name
        </p>
    </div>
}
```

So why would get_User be executed twice?

[image]

Comment: No, that is the query. my Post object has a UserId FK. I get the User information by @post.User.Name

Comment: Out of curiosity, how many posts do you have in the database? 2?

Comment: Joe: Your posted LINQ query only reflects the first of the 3 SQL queries you posted. The two identical SQL queries you have NOT posted.

Comment: @Phil, right now 4, but i just chopped off the other 2 in the image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is because the `@post.User.Name` part is executing for each record. Did the original query return 2 results?

Best way to fix this is in the original query do a select to get all the info you want (Title, ID and Username).

Answer (score 1):

The query is fetching the username for each user. The parameter @p0 is the user ID. If you check the value of it, you will most likely find that it is different for each query.

Answer (score 0):

The Linq statement is not being executed twice. The first query is from the Linq statement, and I am guessing the 2nd and 3rd queries are from your @foreach loop.

Comment: Linq is deferred, so I would think I wouldn't even see the query from that. right?

Comment: What I mean is i would only see the query from my foreach

Comment: Linq is deferred, but it looks like something is causing the statement to be evaluated. The first query is exactly what you wrote in the Linq statement. The other two queries have nothing to do with that Linq statement.